# Force computer setting gpo to work as user settings gpo

Tags: windows, server, windows-server-2012-r2, gpo

I have a own configured GPO for a number of users, where there are administrative templates configured in user configuration and computer configuration.

The users of that gpo wont use the same computer every log in, so the computer settings administrative templates wont work, but the setting of that templates are not in the user's ones to configure them.

Is there any way to force the computer settings on the gpo to act as user settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well , after looking for it I finally found an asnwer:

There is a GPO, called "User Group Policy Loopback Processing Mode". It is located on: `Administrative Templates > System > Group Policy`

I've enabled it and checked merge option, and my problem is gone. Merge, takes AD GPO (both, computer and user) and put it on the remote.

For checking it was working, run the next command:

```
gpupdate /force
```

That force GPOs to update, so you can see if they are getting aplied or not